# I've got 2 buttons, but I want only one of them to check the required fields, but How?

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

I am really new to **PHP** and **HTML**. 
The problem I have now is: 
I've got 2 buttons: (1) Temp (2)Submit, and both of them are created for a form which user can write something on. But some of the form's fields are required, so in HTML I have written "required" in the end of those fields in my form. 
But the problem is, I want the system check those required field when i press the "**Submit**" button, instead of the "**Temp**" button. But I really don't know how?

These are things I have so far:

```
<form action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>   
<div class='well'><strong><h4><center>Intern Record File</center></strong> 
</h4></div>
<br>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Company Name</span>
        <input type="hidden" name="ent_name_title" value="Company Nmae">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ent_name" value="<?php echo $ent_name;?>" required readonly>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Job Name</span>
        <input type="hidden" name="intern_name_title" value="Job Name">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="intern_name" value="<?php echo $intern_name;?>" required readonly>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Job Department</span>
        <input type="hidden" name="ent_acc_dept_title" value="Job Department">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ent_acc_dept" value="<?php echo $ent_acc_dept;?>">
    </div>
<br>
```

Comment: I don't see any buttons

Comment: buttons have types, you can change the default type back to button and it won't act as a form submit. [read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type)

Comment: HI, change Temp button to  <button> and Submit button to <input>

Comment: You can use <a></a> with a btn class(if you are using bootstrap ofc.) for second button. So the page wont submit on second button

Comment: @SeanBright Sorry, I didn't paste that part. 
`<div class="form-group"> 
 <div class= row>
 <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-2 text-center">
 <a href='<?php echo $back_page;?>' class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" role="button">Cancel</a>
 </div>   
        <div class="col-xs-2 text-center">
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" name='tmp'>Temp</button>
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-2 text-center">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" name='submit' 
onclick="return confirm('Temp for edit, if you are sure with your answer then submit!)')"/>Submit</button>`

Comment: @rlemon Thanks for the reply. But i after i changed the type, I can no longer user $_POST['tmp']. But because i have to save what the users have input, which means that the TEMP button serves as a role to save the file temporarily and later the users can modify their files, what can i do if i change the type from submit to others?

Answer (score 0):

You could `preventDefault()` on the click `event` of your `Temp` button

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Answer (score 0):

You could always change the temp button to an `<a></a>` tag styled like a button with an `onclick` event instead of a `href`

Example:

```
<button onclick="functionName();" >Temp</button>
```

I would avoid using a `<input type="submit" />` as this will cause the form data to be submitted (which if they have the required field on them they be validated)

A code snippet

```js
function funTemp() {
  console.log("validation did not fire");
}
```

```css
.btnClass {
  border: 1px solid rgb(36, 39, 41);
  background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="text1" name="text1" required />
  <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" name="submitBtn" />
  <a class="btnClass" onclick="funTemp();">Temp</a>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. But I've still got a little concern here. 
Since the temp button is to serve as a button when the user click on it can temporarily save the files the users have input, there are some PHP code for this part . How can I make it work? (The PHP code is in another comment box. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['tmp'])){
 $content="";
 foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
  $content=$content.htmlspecialchars($key).":".htmlspecialchars($value).";";
 }
 
 //echo $file_path;
 make_txt_file($file_path,$content);
 //redirect to this page with path parameter 
 //$path = urlencode(base64_encode($file_path));
 echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
   window.location.href='".$back_page."';
   </SCRIPT>");
 break;
}` 
Since i need to use this PHP code to make a .txt file, without submit type, I can no longer use $_POST.

Comment: You could add it the php code in the onclick. I am not 100% sure as this depends on what you want to accomplish